# What's the word for a gifted service (or intangible good)?

Tags: vocabulary

Yesterday, my employer took me and 50 other team members to see the new Star Wars movie! During office hours! All paid for by the company!

They just sent us a letter saying: "thanks for coming". I want to write back: "thanks for forfeiting company time and buying us tickets!" or:
"thank you for this christmas gift"

Maybe the word I am looking for is "Gesture"? ("Thank you for this kind gesture and for organizing a great movie event")

Comment: I like "gesture", because it puts the focus on the act of giving rather than the event, but you could also describe it as an unexpected "perk", "bonus", etc.

Comment: All teams and departments in any company could have "entertainment budget" for their team meeting, gathering, drinks, movies and parties, etc. You can use the word ***entertainment*** for the free movie provided by your company. Do you really have to write back? That's part of your salary and actually you earned it. :)

Comment: @Rathony, while I assume it was budgeted, I am not entitled to it. Anyway, thanks for your kind attention :)

Comment: When you become senior enough to be agonized by your subordinates, you will automatically think they are not entitled to it. But until then, enjoy the budget. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. *Gesture* is the word.

*[Gesture](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gesture)*

> any action, courtesy, communication, etc., intended for effect or as a formality; considered expression; demonstration

[Dictionary.com]

And that's one awesome gesture, to say the least!
I trust you were all taken by surprise by your company's gesture! Why don'y you just say that?

> Thank you so much for the sweet surprise. We thoroughly enjoyed our time and this gesture will forever be etched in our memories !

Comment: thanks for the answer. I liked the additional touch of expressing how much fun it was for me.
It wasn't a surprise - we knew about this a week ago.
Still, it was a surprise to hear about it, when we did, last week :)
It was unexpected because we already had our xmas lunch a day before yesterday and we also have a lot of work.

Comment: 'forever etched in our memories' seems a little, hmm, *gushy* and over the top. A message thanking them along these lines is great, polite and could be remembered as a positive thing about you, but going over the top may be considered a little creepy? YMMV.

Comment: @MarvMills - May be a bit exaggerated but definitely not creepy, IMO. I posted the answer as if I were to thank my organization (I can only *dream* about my org throwing a surprise movie bash:/). Then again, if OP feels the sentences convey a little too much than what they ought to, they can always edit according to their needs!

Answer (score 2):

***[Christmas] treat*** might convey what you're looking for.

> treat
>
> : an event or item that is out of the ordinary and gives great pleasure. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/pt/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o/ingl%C3%AAs-americano/treat)
>
> : a) an occurrence in which you pay for someone's food, drink, or entertainment; b) something pleasant or amusing that is unusual or unexpected [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treat)
>
> : a) entertainment, food, drink, etc., given by way of compliment or as an expression of friendly regard; b) anything that affords particular pleasure or enjoyment. [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/treat)